# How to find specific item in Crawl Log Search Service Application?

Tags: search, error

I have a SharePoint Site that have around 1 million items that can be crawled. Of these 1 million, there are around 6 items that can't be searched.

I want to 'recrawl' these items using the 'crawl this item in the next crawl'. Problem is, there are around 90,000 items in the error crawl log, and I'm having a hard time filtering through these.

Is there anyway to manually recrawl the specific item? I am using SharePoint 2010.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Re-index feature has been introduced in SharePoint 2013.I don't think it is available in SharePoint 2010 .

Please ensure the crawl account should have a "Full Read" property, using a Web Application policy.I think your crawl account do not have full control for those items.

To ensure that crawl account have permissions to read those items  log in using the crawl account to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks Amit! Found out that I needed to place %20 for the URL with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if you can drill down till items but you can do for the list/library or site itself.

Re-index a document library or a list

On the site, go to the list or library that you want to re-index.

In the ribbon, click the Library tab or the List tab.

In the Library ribbon, choose Library Settings,
or,

In the List ribbon choose List Settings.

On the Settings page, under General Settings, choose Advanced settings.

Scroll down to Reindex Document Library or Reindex List, and click the button. The content will be re-indexed during the next scheduled crawl.

https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Manually-request-crawling-and-reindexing-of-a-site-9afa977d-39de-4321-b4ca-8c7c7e6d264e

Also check this one:

https://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/selective-crawling-in-sharepoint-2010-with-f-selenium/